# in MATLAB Guide, take multiple inputs in one box using for

Tags: matlab

I want to take multiple values with for loop.

```
firstVal   matlab.ui.control.NumericEditField

...

attributesNum = size(matrix,2) - 1 ; 
X = zeros(attributesNum,1);
    for i=1:attributesNum
    values = app.firstVal;
    X(i,1) = values;
end
```

but it does not work. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding [waitfor](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitfor.html), but it doesn't make a lot of sense as a user interface...

Here is an example for taking multiple values with for loop:

```
for i = 1:attributesNum
    waitfor(app.firstVal, 'Value');

    value = app.firstVal.Value;
    X(i) = value;               
end
```

---

Here is a complete sample built using [MATLAB App Designer](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/app-designer.html).
You can copy and paste it to an `m` file to see how it works.
Most of the code was generated by App Designer.
The relevant code is in `function startupFcn(app)`:

```
classdef app1 < matlab.apps.AppBase

    % Properties that correspond to app components
    properties (Access = public)
        UIFigure        matlab.ui.Figure
        EditFieldLabel  matlab.ui.control.Label
        firstVal        matlab.ui.control.NumericEditField
        ValuesLabel     matlab.ui.control.Label
        EnteravalueandpressEnter5timesLabel  matlab.ui.control.Label
    end


    % Callbacks that handle component events
    methods (Access = private)

        % Code that executes after component creation
        function startupFcn(app)
            matrix = zeros(1, 5); % 1x5 elements matrix (just for example).

            attributesNum = size(matrix, 2);
            X = zeros(attributesNum, 1);

            for i = 1:attributesNum
                waitfor(app.firstVal, 'Value');

                value = app.firstVal.Value;
                X(i) = value;
                app.firstVal.Value = Inf; %Set to Inf every iteration, because waitfor waits for a change in value (and you may need to enter same value twice).

                %Update text of ValuesLabel (for demostrating the concept).
                text = ['Values: ', sprintf('%.1f, ', X(1:i))];
                app.ValuesLabel.Text = text(1:end-2);
            end

            %Display X in Command window for testing
            disp(X)
        end
    end

    % Component initialization
    methods (Access = private)

        % Create UIFigure and components
        function createComponents(app)

            % Create UIFigure and hide until all components are created
            app.UIFigure = uifigure('Visible', 'off');
            app.UIFigure.Position = [100 100 369 256];
            app.UIFigure.Name = 'UI Figure';

            % Create EditFieldLabel
            app.EditFieldLabel = uilabel(app.UIFigure);
            app.EditFieldLabel.HorizontalAlignment = 'right';
            app.EditFieldLabel.Position = [45 123 56 22];
            app.EditFieldLabel.Text = 'Edit Field';

            % Create firstVal
            app.firstVal = uieditfield(app.UIFigure, 'numeric');
            app.firstVal.Position = [116 123 100 22];
            app.firstVal.Value = Inf;

            % Create ValuesLabel
            app.ValuesLabel = uilabel(app.UIFigure);
            app.ValuesLabel.Position = [49 51 297 22];
            app.ValuesLabel.Text = 'Values: ';

            % Create EnteravalueandpressEnter5timesLabel
            app.EnteravalueandpressEnter5timesLabel = uilabel(app.UIFigure);
            app.EnteravalueandpressEnter5timesLabel.Position = [51 181 215 22];
            app.EnteravalueandpressEnter5timesLabel.Text = 'Enter a value and press Enter (5 times)';

            % Show the figure after all components are created
            app.UIFigure.Visible = 'on';
        end
    end

    % App creation and deletion
    methods (Access = public)

        % Construct app
        function app = app1

            % Create UIFigure and components
            createComponents(app)

            % Register the app with App Designer
            registerApp(app, app.UIFigure)

            % Execute the startup function
            runStartupFcn(app, @startupFcn)

            if nargout == 0
                clear app
            end
        end

        % Code that executes before app deletion
        function delete(app)

            % Delete UIFigure when app is deleted
            delete(app.UIFigure)
        end
    end
end
```

---

Here is how the sample user interface looks like:

[image]

Comment: Firstly, I am very thankful for your answer. But the link is broken and when I run the code, there is no open window. Please, can you send me the link again?

Comment: First link: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitfor.html

Comment: Second link: https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/app-designer.html

Comment: Both works in my browser.

Comment: I tested the code in MATLAB R2019a and in MATLAB R2016a, and it's working. In case your MATLAB version is before R2016a the code is not going to work.

Comment: I updated and It works. thanks a lot